# Synchronising @Transactional method

Tags: java, spring, transactions, synchronized

I have a synchronised method with an annotation `@Transactional`, like below:

```
@Transactional
public synchronized void myMethod() { ... }
```

The goal is to make sure no two threads calling this method (i.e. doing the same critical code section) at the same time, and have the changes in the transaction committed BEFORE another threads enters the method.

Unfortunately, it turns out that another thread CAN enter the method, while the previous thread hasn't committed the transaction yet. Tracing the code, the commit is done within the proxy method and hence not protected by `synchronized`.

One solution I have at the moment is to have the caller class to synchronise calling this method:

```
synchronized (this) {
    myClass.myMethod();
}
```

which I don't like, as the responsibility of synchronising creeps into the caller class.

What is the correct way to achieve the above goal while keeping both synchronise and transactional in the same class?

Comment: One comment that comes to mind is that, if your `@Transactional` method is called when a transaction is already active, it will participate in that transaction and the commit will occur outside of the synchronization boundary anyway. You may want something like `@Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW)` for it to be fully autonomous. Another thing is that, even when you protect the critical section with `synchronized`, this is good only for a single VM; spawn another instance of your server and all is lost. Perhaps you could acquire a DB row-level lock instead? (just speculating)

Comment: You could make the `@Transactional` method private, and have a `public synchronized` method to access it

Comment: And @Jorn, that would require _self autowiring_ which is a weird pattern in my opinion.

Comment: Why? You don't need to inject a second instance of yourself, you just need to call the private method from the public one (using `this`)